# Identification to a sql database with sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect to my database which is on a microsoft sql server with sqlsrv_connect

But I have an error that shows that the provided certificate chain does not have an authority that is not trusted

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 08001
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [1] => -2146893019
        [code] => -2146893019
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate cha�ne has �t� provided by an autorit� that is not approv�e.
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain has �t� provided by an autorit� that is not approved�.
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 08001 
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
        [1] => -2146893019 
        [code] => -2146893019 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]The client could not �tablish the connection 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]The client could not �tablish the connection 
    )
```

I have heard about :

```
encrypt=true trustservercertificate=true
```

But I don't know how to integrate it in my php code without error

```php
<?php

$serverName = "";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "Affichage",
    "UID" => "sa",
    "PWD" => "mrsushi"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if ($conn) {
        echo "Connexion établie.<br />";
} else {
        echo "La connexion n'a pu être établie.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

A new error come when i try the new code :

```
    La connexion n'a pu être établie.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Ecran" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Ecran" requested by the login. The login failed. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Ecran" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Ecran" requested by the login. The login failed. ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php it references https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options

> TrustServerCertificate 1 or true to trust certificate

```
<?php

$serverName = "";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "Affichage",
    "UID" => "sa",
    "PWD" => "mrsushi",
    "TrustServerCertificate" => true
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if ($conn) {
        echo "Connexion établie.<br />";
} else {
        echo "La connexion n'a pu être établie.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Comment: @comple_stranger Another error appeared as my login failed to identify itself

Comment: edit your question with the new error message

Comment: that is the new error message :(

Comment: since it's the "sa" user either it's disabled or your password is wrong and/or the database "Ecran" doesn't exist